# Creating a basic excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm no excel expert by any stretch and need some help with a formula from you helpful people.

As per the screenshot below, I'm wanting to cumulatively decrease the figure of $300,000 when a number is entered in the loss estimate field (I).

However, I only want a figure to show in the Aggregate column (K) when something is entered in the loss estimate column (I).

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks.

[image: Excel Screen shot]

Comment: Add to your question: What OS. and a OS tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your requirement, try this solution. I assume the output is not affected by the information present in Column J.

In this example cell K2 holds 300000 which is the starting amount.

In K3 put the following formula and drag it down.

```
=$K$2-SUM($I$3:I3)
```

As you specify the loss estimates in I, the last value in K will be the cumulative reduction from earlier 300000 in K2.

However if the contents in J affect the output then a different solution would be needed.

[image]

To leave the unused cells in Col K blank, use the following formula in K3 and drag it down up to the indented cells.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I3),"",$K$2-SUM($I$3:I3))
```

Just note that depending upon the regional settings for List Separator you may have to replace comma (,) with semicolon (;) for the formula to work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is great! and yes column J isn't relevant. I also want cells K7-K-11 in your example to be blank, unless a figure is entered in column I - is this possible. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: See the updated answer. Just wrap the original formula in an IF to check for blanks/non blanks in col I. In future if Col I values will be formula based, then ISBLANK will not work, you will have to check using ISNUMBER function.